# Invariants of the Determinant Form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, invariant-theory

Consider   a form of degree $r$  in $n$,  that is, a homogeneous polynomial

$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=\sum_{i_1+\ldots i_n=r}\alpha_{i_1 ... i_n}x_1^{i_1} ... x_n^{i_n}
$$

After the linear change of variables 
 $$\delta : x^\prime_1\rightarrow\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ij}x_{j}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;1\leq i\leq n,$$

where $\beta_{ij}$ are real or complex numbers, we obtain a new form

$$f^\prime(x^\prime_1, \ldots, x^\prime_n)=\sum_{i_1+\ldots i_n=r}\alpha^\prime_{i_1 ... i_n}{x^\prime_1}^{i_1} ... {x^\prime_n}^{i_n}
$$

An invariant of the  form $f$ is a polynomial function 
of the coefficients $\alpha_{i_1 ... i_n}$ that changes only by a factor equal to a 
power of the  determinant of the linear transformation $\delta$ if one replaces the coefficients 
 $\alpha_{i_1 ... i_n}$ of the given base form by the corresponding coefficients 
$\alpha^\prime_{i_1 ... i_n}$of the linearly transformed form.

This is the definition of invariants given by Hilbert in "Theory of Algebraic Invariants".

My question is: Consider the determinant of the matrix $A=[x_{ij}]_{n×n}$ as a polynomial in the ring $R[x_{11},…,x_{nn}]$. The determinant is a homogeneous polynomial and hence a  form. What are the invariants of the determinant form?

Remark: I put this question yesterday in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642843/invariants-of-the-determinant-form
But was not answered. Also there are no comments.

Comment: I believe that you cannot speak about invariants of a single form; it's invariants of **forms** (say, with given $n$ and $r$).

Comment: As Alex says, the question does not make sense. Hilbert dicusses the invariants of a *generic* form - in modern language, of the space of forms of given degree in a given number of variables.

Comment: The space of skew $n$-forms on $\mathbb R^n$ is 1-dimensional. There are just 2 orbits under $GL(n)$, zero, and the rest. So no invariants. Under $SO(n)$, each elements of $\Lambda^n (\mathbb R^n)^*$ is invariant.

Comment: Actually, I think that there is an interpretation of this question that does make sense: If ${\mathcal{R}}_{n,r}$ is the ring of invariants (in Hilbert's sense) of polynomials of degree $r$ in $n$ variables with coefficients in a field $F$, then any given form $f$ of degree $r$ in those $n$ variables induces a map $e_f:{\mathcal{R}}_{n,r}\to F$, and the the answer to the question "What are the invariants of $f$?" could just mean "What is $e_f$?". In this particular case, it seems that the OP would like be able to recognize when a polynomial of degree $n$ in $n^2$ variables is the determinant.